# PIC16F877A : How to keep controller awake?

Tags: pic, uart, microchip, mplabx, c18

I am using Pic16f877a for a Serial Communication. I have a PC-based application which sends data to Microcontroller. Microcontroller receives the data and transmit it over I2C.

But, I am facing an issue. After every transmission, I have to reset the microcontroller for next transmission. I am using ISR (Interrupt Service Routine) for receiving Serial Data. But even ISR is not been called for the next available data. And I have to end up reseting the device.

Part of my Code for reference :

```
int main()
{
    UARTInit();
    idmInitI2C();

    TRISB7 = 0;
    bool toggleBit = false;
    while (1)
    {    
        RB7 = toggleBit;
//        __delay_us(10);

        if ( UART_GetRecvByteStatus() ) {
            UART_SetRecvByteStatus(false);              // Set Received flag False
            receiveDataPkt();                           // Receive Incoming data
        }

        if ( isDataPktReceived ) {
            initIDComm();
            isDataPktReceived = false;
        }

        toggleBit != toggleBit;
    }
    return 0;
}

void receiveDataPkt()
{
    char buffer = NULL;                             // Load character receive to output buffer
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int buf_count = 0;                              // Count character received
    int dly = 50;                                   // Initialize delay duration local to this section

    initBuffers();

    while ( !TXSTAbits.TRMT );                      // Wait until Transmit shift Register is not Empty, 
                                                // a transmission is in   progress or queued in the transmit buffer

    while ( buf_count != MAX_PKT_SIZE ){

        buffer = UART_Read();                             // Read Data


        if ( buffer == 0x00 ){
             break;
        }

        if ( buf_count < MAX_BUF_SIZE ) {
            data_Pkt_1[ i ] = buffer;               // Store data to Char Array 
            i++;
        } else {
            data_Pkt_2[ j ] = buffer;               // Store data to Char Array
            j++;
        }

        if ( ( data_Pkt_1[ 1 ] == READ ) && ( data_Pkt_1[ 4 ] == ETX ) ){
            break;
        }
        buf_count++;                                // Increase Count
    }

    while (dly){                                    // delay
        dly--;
     }

    if (OERR){
        CREN = 0;
        CREN = 1;
    }
    RCIE = 1;                                       // Enable Receive Interrupt

    isDataPktReceived = true;
    }

 void interrupt ISR(void)
 {
     if (RCIF)
     {
         RCIE = 0;
         if ( OERR ){
            CREN = 0;
            CREN = 1;
         }

        UART_SetRecvByteStatus( true );         // Signal for Received Byte
    } 
}
```

What can be done to resolve the issue ?? I want to keep it always awake so that ISR can be called for each incoming data.

EDIT:

function UART_Read() for reference:

```
char UART_Read()
{
    int count = 0;
    char data = 0x00;

    while ( !RCIF ){
        if ( count >= 10 ){
            break;
        }
        __delay_ms(10);
        count++;
    }

    if ( RCIF ){
        data = RCREG;
    }

    return data;
}
```

( Also I am receiving Max 133 Bytes in one Transaction. )

Comment: If I remember rightly, you have to clear the interrupt flag (RCIF=0) and leave the interrupt enabled (RCIE=1).

Comment: @pjc50, thanks for response. I am setting (RCIE=1) in function receiveDataPkt();thats why i cleared (RCIE=0) under ISR.

Comment: @David, Datasheet says "Flag bit RCIF is a read only bit, which is cleared by the hardware. It is cleared when the RCREG
register has been read and is empty."

Comment: Does toggleBit != toggleBit; definitely do what you think it does or does it just evaluate to false and do nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a byte comes into the receive ISR, if the interrupt flag is set, you reset it, and then set a flag using UART_SetRecvByteStatus( true ).  The ISR also disables the receive interrupt.  You do not read a byte out of the UART receive register at this time.  Not good.

In main, inside the while(1) loop, if the RecvByteStatus flag is set, you reset it and call receiveDataPkt().  In that function, inside the while loop: while ( buf_count != MAX_PKT_SIZE ), you make repeated calls to read the UART buffer.

But except for the first time, you don't really know if a character is available (unless the UART_Read() blocks waiting for the receive buffer to be full, and I doubt that). While you are making all of these calls to UART_Read(), the ISR is not triggered because the interrupt is disabled.

You exit receiveDataPkt() only if you have received one of two special characters.  If these are missing, you will continue to receive characters until the buffers are full.

The way this should work, is you should leave the interrupt enabled, and you should be putting characters into a circular buffer inside the ISR, and then pulling them off in the receiveDataPkt() function.  This entails using two pointers, one for keeping track of the next byte for the ISR, and another for pulling the bytes off the buffer.  If you are not familiar with circular buffers, [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#Start.2Fend_pointers_.28head.2Ftail.29).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Frankly speaking, I am not familiar with Circular Buffer. So, I need to study about it. I have also edited my Question, with UART_Read() function. Please have  a look and provide me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: @skg Thanks for adding the code for UART_Read().  It's good that you are using a counter to avoid waiting forever for a character,  however 10 * 100 µs is only 1 ms.  When you exit, you still read the contents of the receive register, so you will be adding the last character to the buffer twice.  You need to make the timeout in the much longer, maybe 100 ms, and then handle the error condition better (maybe return 0).  Also the dly loop in receiveDataPkt will be very quick (100 µs?), why didn't you call __delay_us() instead?

Comment: thanks. I have modified UART_Read() as per your suggestions. Also modifed receivedDataPkt(). Added check for the buffer , if buffer== NULL then break. Please have look and provide  me your valuable suggestions.